Github Personal Access token gets Permission Denied when trying to pull down images from ghcr.io
When I try to pull down images on ghcr.io, I'm getting "permission denied". My token has read:packages.
❯ podman pull ghcr.io/acme-integrations/cpanel-plugins-build-image:main

Trying to pull ghcr.io/webpros-integrations/cpanel-plugins-build-image:main...
Error: initializing source docker://ghcr.io/acme-integrations/cpanel-plugins-build-image:main: reading manifest main in ghcr.io/acme-integrations/cpanel-plugins-build-image: denied

Why is this and how do I solve this?

Need to "Authorize" Token
For me, it was because my token was not authorized with SSO. I had to do that manually in the web UI.

